# AllJoyn mailing list

Tags: alljoyn

What happened to Alljoyn mailing lists? there was a wealth of information there, is there another way to access it?

[AllJoyn Mailing list](https://lists.allseenalliance.org/mailman/listinfo)

the above is not accessible anymore. Can we still continue to develop using AllJoyn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can still continue do develop using Alljoyn. Useful information:

- Here on stackoverflow
- https://ask.allseenalliance.org/questions/
- https://wiki.allseenalliance.org/

And finally the mailing list on alljoyn.org:

- https://lists.alljoyn.org/mailman/listinfo

Comment: @SmoothOperator did it help?

Comment: Certainly the mailing list is back up and running.

Comment: The allseenalliance domain will be going away soon, but the resources should have redirects